# rails content_for does not get executed when doing render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a `content_for` inside my view for logging in and in the sessions controller, I have `render :new` when the user does not enter valid credentials. However, when it does `render :new`, I get a black and white page without any css or js. This is how my `content_for` look like

```
<% content_for :head do %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "user_sessions/new" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'user_sessions/new.onready' %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a work around to make sure that the above code gets executed when I do `render`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess would be that you're not including the `content_for` anywhere. In `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` (or whichever layout you're using for this page) make sure you've got something like the following:

```
<head>
  <!-- your regular head content goes here -->
  <%= content_for :head %>
</head>
```

When you pass a block to `content_for`, the contents of the block are stored to be used elsewhere. The call to `content_for` without a block will then insert that stored content.

See [the docs for `content_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) for more info.

Comment: RonaldOnRails answer should be the accepted answer here.

Comment: This answer is correct for Rails 3, which was the latest version when this question was asked.

Answer (score 4):

```
<head><%= content_for :head %></head>
```

didn't work for me, but

```
<head><%= yield :head %></head>
```

worked, i guess this is the right to do

Just remembering: `yield` calls the content, and `:head` is the parameter for `content_for` that u put in your rendered view, so u can put pieces of code anywhere of the application.html u want

Comment: This worked exactly as it's intended to…  Strangely I don't remember having to do it this way in earlier versions of Rails.  It may have changed.  Regardless, thanks for this!